# Font artifacts with ClearType Switched on

Tags: fonts, windows-10, cleartype

I have an issue where having ClearType enabled in Windows 10 gives them horrible blocky artefacts around some letters - more visible on certain kinds of backgrounds. This one is particularly bad, you can see yellow banding around letters on this background.

[image]

Look what's happening here around "mode" and "delay"(bright blocks around the font):

[image]

I've tried going through the "Adjust ClearType" creator several times but with no success, no matter which option I pick I always get this strange banding. The only "fix" for this is to disable clear type altogether - but then the fonts look awful obviously. Any idea what it could possibly be? Never seen anything like this.

It's on Windows 10 Home, 1803 build.